# Tab data lost on selected item changed MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, mvvm

I have been trying to do this for ages and having no joy whatsoever.

I have a ribbon window of the following hierarchy:

- MainWindow

  - MainContent (Tab Control)

    - TabContainerViewModel

      - ViewModelBase

View model base has an ObservableCollection of tabs type ViewModelBase. The Tab Control itself is binding fine to these, displaying appropriate view models. I have 2 problems however, I want a "NotepadView" (Of type viewmodelbase) to be replicated numerous times (one view many view models).

At the minute, I have 4 views (NotePadViewModelx where x is 1-4) with corresponding viewmodels, this is because each view had the same text per tab. Now I have individual views per tab.

When I type into tab 1 and switch to tab 2, I lose what I typed in tab one when I click back.

Could somebody help to provide me with a solution to these problems?

- One NotepadView for multiple instances of the ViewModel
- Keeping information when tabs change

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So that means you are using only the same instance of notepadview control?

Comment: In my solution explorer I want one notepadview and one notepadview but I can have many instances of them in my tab control. All the notepadview has is a textbox on it, in theory I could template the content of the tab item's to just have a text box but i'm trying to learn as much MVVM as possible from doing this.

Comment: As a further summary to the question - My textboxes are bound to a Text property in the viewmodelbase which has an updatesourcetrigger of property changed. This is fine, when I click the "New Notepad" button, the Text property is set back to nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the Header and Text properties into ViewModelBase and then when I add a ViewModelBase as a Tab I used a DataTemplate for the ViewModelBase as I was for the NotePadViewModels with just a textbox.

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:ViewModelBase}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
  </DataTemplate>
```

As apose to using this:

```
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:NotepadViewModel}">
      <ui:NotePadView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:NotepadViewModel2}">
      <ui:NotePadView2 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:NotepadViewModel3}">
      <ui:NotePadView3 DataContext="{Binding}"/>
  </DataTemplate>
```

Thanks to Rachel for a small hint to the problem. Basically on the previous way nothing was actually binding within the datatemplate so it had no reason to keep it as a resource. By adding a default textbox within a datatemplate I can add as many notepads as I want whilst being able to add other views which don't need a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WPF will re-use a `TabItem` when possible and simply replace the `DataContext` behind it. If your properties are not bound to anything in the `DataContext`, they will get reset when you switch tabs.

So to get your changes to persist, you need to store them in the `DataContext`

For example,

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyNotepadVMCollection}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SomePropertyOnViewModel}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: I am using a style for my tab control and then binding the item template to the list of view models and appropriate views. Should I need another view for my tab, for example settings this will have a textbox on wouldnt it?

Comment: @LukeHennerley I was going to reply, but see you already got it sorted out :)